# How to search Pivot table for multiple matches with AND condition

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, pivot, pivot-table

I have 3 tables including one pivot in my laravel 5.3 project

**jobs**

```
+----+----------------------+
| id |        title         |
+----+----------------------+
| 1  | PHP Developer        |
| 2  | JavaScript Developer |
| 3  | UI Developer         |
+----+----------------------+
```

**skills**

```
+----+-------+
| id | title |
+----+-------+
| 1  | PHP   |
| 2  | js    |
| 3  | CSS   |
| 4  | HTML  |
+----+-------+
```

**job_skill** (pivot table)

```
+--------+----------+
| job_id | skill_id |
+--------+----------+
|     1  |        1 |
|     1  |        2 |
|     1  |        4 |
|     2  |        2 |
|     3  |        3 |
|     3  |        4 |
+--------+----------+
```

I have **belongsToMany** relationship defined in jobs and skills models.
Now, I need to match all the jobs which has multiple skills.

for example

```
skills[]=php => [PHP Developer]
skills[]=js => [JavaScript Developer]
skills[]=HTML =>[PHP Developer, UI Developer]
skills[]=HTML,CSS => [UI Developer]
```

I tried with `whereHas` in eloquent, but since I have to use `AND` between skills, it is returning nothing

```
$jobs = Post::whereHas('skills', function ($query) {
    foreach($skills as $skill) {
        $query->where('name', '=', $skill);
    }
})->get();
```

Please point me in right direction either with eloquent or SQL solution

Comment: Do you already know how to achieve the expected result using pure SQL Queries?

Comment: No, i mean no just for 15 chars

Answer (score 0):

You could use a `whereIn` clause to find matching skill names:

```
$searchSkills = ['PHP', 'CSS'];

Post::whereHas('skills', function($query) use ($searchSkills){
    $query->whereIn('name', $searchSkills);
})->get();
```

...would return all posts with at least one skill named `PHP` or `CSS`.

This code has not been tested. Please let me know if it works.

Answer (score 0):

One option is to use multiple `whereHas` as:

```
$query = Post::query();

foreach ($skills as $skill) {
    $query->whereHas('skills', function ($q) use($skill) {
        $q->where('name', $skill);
    });
}

$posts = $query->get();
```

OR

Assuming you have an array of skill `id` as:

```
$skill_ids = [1, 3];
```

Then you can try as:

```
Post::whereHas('skills', function($q) use($skill_ids) {
        $q->whereIn('skill_id', $skill_ids)
          ->groupBy('post_id')
          ->havingRaw('COUNT(DISTINCT skill_id) = '.count($skill_ids));
    })->get();
```